# Setting up an array in a session cookie in javascript and access to it in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an array of `productId` and I want add them to session cookie in javascript and access to that  array in that session cookie form asp.net core 2.2 controller action

I already do some work but my session cookie is null

For controller part:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPersonSkills(AddPersonSkillsViewModel model)
{
    string PersonIdKey = "_id";
    int? persoId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(PersonIdKey);

    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

For the javascript part the array already have some ids:

```
var selected = [2,6,9,7,2,8];
function addToSelected() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("_Selected", JSON.stringify(selected));
}
```

I want get those id from javascript session to my controller so I could continue my work there

Comment: `sessionStorage` is not a cookie.

Comment: then how should i perform the action i described

Comment: Save the items in a cookie? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: i have array. that document cookie just get one item at time and i should set a cookie for each item of array and my array list is dynamic and it changes over time and how can save those cookies in controller action